# Ampersand & is not correctly represented in swagger UI of WEB API documentation when it is inside a code markup

Tags: xml, swagger, comments, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to add remarks to the API endpoint via XML comments using "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1".

The problem is with ampersands inside the code markup blocks. They are not rendered right or comments are not rendered at all.

I have tried escaping `&` by replacing it with & and unicode specific representations, however they are still rendered in UI as `&amp;`. Also tried wrapping it in  .
If I leave just `&` comments are not rendered at all as it is not valid in XML comments.

````
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all entries
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Sample request:
    /// ```
    ///     GET <![CDATA[ /api/entries/1?month=5&day=2 ]]>
    /// ```
    /// </remarks>
    [HttpGet("/all")]
    public IActionResult Get(int month, int day)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
````

Instead of seeing

Sample request:

```
GET  /api/entries/1?month=5&amp;day=2
```

I would like to see

Sample request:

```
GET  /api/entries/1?month=5&day=2
```

Comment: Can you try the latest version of Swashbuckle (5.0.0-rc2) and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Thank you for an idea, @Helen, unfortunately, there is no difference with the new version (5.0.0-rc2) .

Answer (score 0):

2022 and I was also having issues with my XML doc not showing in swagger because of the use of ampersand (`&`). Visual Studio 2022 IntelliSense shows:

> XML comment has badly formed XML -- Reference to undefined entity.

My solution was to replace all `&` with `&amp;` in my XML. Using your example above, try using:

```
/// GET  /api/entries/1?month=5`&amp;`day=2
```

instead of:

```
/// GET  /api/entries/1?month=5`&`day=2
```